# function with in and out parameter error PLS-00103

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am struggling to create a function with in and out parameter to return the value unfortunately I am getting a error on the first line i am unable to figure out the issue could i get some assistance to where i am going wrong.

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following: := . ) , @ % default character The symbol ":= was inserted before "(" to continue.

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_LOCATION_Test (l_con_id in NUMBER, l_con_name out VARCHAR2(15)
RETURN NUMBER
IS LOCATION VARCHAR2(30);

BEGIN
SELECT LOCATION INTO LOCATION FROM LDS_CONSULTANT WHERE CONSULTANT_ID = l_con_id;

SELECT CST_NAME INTO l_con_name FROM LDS_CONSULTANT WHERE CONSULTANT_ID = l_con_id;




RETURN l_con_id;
END;
```

Comment: Functions do return values. Why do you need an out parameter in the function? You need to read about functions.

Comment: I'm wanting to return more than one value

Comment: If you want to return more than one value, use a procedure or return a record (or object type). Your current approach of returning one value through the parameter list of the function and another via RETURN is confusing and will be difficult to use and maintain.

Comment: @gozzlia - And watch Steven's videos and read his books over this weekend. It is all covered in his books and videos. Thank you, Steven.

Comment: for assignment for advance code i think it works thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closing parentheses is missing at the end of the parameter list of the function(and *length specification* is not allowed there). Use the following instead :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_LOCATION_TEST
(l_con_id in NUMBER, l_con_name out VARCHAR2)--^*^parentheses is missing,  
                                             -- and length specification is wrong here 
RETURN NUMBER IS  
 LOCATION VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT LOCATION INTO LOCATION FROM LDS_CONSULTANT WHERE CONSULTANT_ID = l_con_id;    
  SELECT CST_NAME INTO l_con_name FROM LDS_CONSULTANT WHERE CONSULTANT_ID = l_con_id;

RETURN l_con_name; -- I suppose you want to return this variable which is of type "out".
END;
```